# Thread-safe trace listener based on XmlWriterTraceListener

Tags: .net, thread-safety, extend, tracelistener

I want to replace default Microsoft's XmlTraceListener with a listener which switches files based on file size limit or current date. I want to keep the default XmlTraceListener file format so I can open files with the ServiceTraceViewer tool.

I found an article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30956/A-Rolling-XmlWriterTraceListener but from comments it seems that this listener has some instabilities even after suggested patches applied.

Then I found Microsoft's own implementation of CircularListener http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395205.aspx

I wanted to extend it, but noticed that it has

```
static CircularStream m_stream = null;
```

and later this variable is being accessed without locks. When reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx I discovered that even XmlWriterTraceListener itself is not thread-safe. MSDN says:

> Because System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener is not thread-safe,
>   the trace source may lock resources exclusively when outputting
>   traces. When many threads output traces to a trace source configured
>   to use this listener, resource contention may occur, which results in
>   a significant performance issue. To resolve this problem, you should
>   implement a custom listener that is thread-safe.

So essentially this means that `TraceListener.IsThreadSafe` property is left as `false` for XmlWriterTraceListener, so then the higher level tracing system is locking each time when TraceData / TraceEvent is called, am I right?

Will there be any benefit from adding a lock around that `static CircularStream m_stream` and returning `true` form the overriden `IsThreadSafe`  property ? Or maybe it will be the same thing that is already being done in the XmlTraceListener?

What can I do to make CircularTraceListener thread-safe and efficient?

Comment: Have you tried it in the default configuration with multiple threads and determined that the locking behavior causes a problem? If you want to add synchronization, you have to do a lot more than just lock around that variable declaration. You'll have to lock around each access to the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `CircularTraceListener` is basically flawed.  As you've noticed there is a `static` `m_stream`.  But, even worse, when you construct a `CircularTraceListener` it passes along the new stream to the base (`XmlWriterTraceListener`).  This means that although `CircularTraceListener` only knows about the *last* created stream, the base class is potentially using one of many streams.  And, of course, if the `CircularTraceListener` gets disposed, the base class will dispose the shared `m_stream` object.

I'd recommend you'd not base anything from `CircularTraceListener` and start from scratch.

## update:

I've had much better luck with things like log4net and NLog for things like circular logging.